# Graphql on Nuxt - Fragment Types

Tags: vue.js, graphql, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

When I send the request to my Graphql API gets me errors like following, request ending successful but console shows;

[image]

I have got a fragmentTypes.json file but I don't know how I integrate to Nuxt and Nuxt config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

permanent solution [is here](https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module/issues/120#issuecomment-482189378) thank you for your interesting